# sed / awk match second occurrence of regex in a file, and replace whole line

Tags: awk, sed, replace

Trying to have sed or awk do the following:

1. Look through file
2. Capture on a string + regex (`remote_addrs.*`)
3. Replace the whole line with something different, so "a line that has "remote_addrs" and anything after it" replace it.

Example file:

```
dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 2.2.2.2
woodchuck
```

Want it changed to this:
Example file:

```
dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3
woodchuck
```

Tried using the following:

```
sed -z 's/remote_addrs.*/remote_addrs\ =\ 3.3.3.3/2' file
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/remote_addrs.*/remote_addrs\ =\ 3.3.3.3/2' file
```

but sed refuses to replace everything after that occurrence. This seems to only work with a single string.

This **MUST** be accomplished **without giving specific line numbers**, the line position of "remote_addrs" must be variable.

Comment: Why did you escape the space and especially `3`? `\3` is a backreference to Group #3, and there no single group in your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew woops, Edited, had the "\" in the wrong spot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a GNU `sed`, so I am also posting a GNU `sed` solution:

```
sed -z 's/remote_addrs.*/remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3/2m' file
```

Note:

- `\3` (used in the initial version of your now edited question) is a backreference to Group #3, and there no single group in your regex. So, the escape should be removed
- You need not escape spaces
- `\z` makes line breaks part of pattern space, and thus `.` matches them. You need to turn on "multiline" mode, and add `m` flag, so that  a `.` pattern could not match line break chars.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TWuHlc):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 2.2.2.2
woodchuck'
 
sed -z 's/remote_addrs.*/remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3/2m' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3
woodchuck
```

Comment: "You need to turn on "multiline" mode, and add m"
That was it! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Although Wiktor's nice solution has been accepted, how about an `awk` solution (JFYI):

```
awk '/remote_addrs.*/ && c++==1 {sub(/remote_addrs.*/, "remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3")} 1' file
```

- The first match of the regex just increments the variable `c` without invoking the statement within `{...}`.
- The second match executes the `sub()` statement.
- The final `1` tells `awk` to print the current record.

Answer (score 0):

With **awk** you can try this

```
$ cat file
dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 2.2.2.2
woodchuck

$ awk 'set==1 && /remote_addrs/{ $0="remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3" }
    /remote_addrs/{ set=1 } 1' file
dog
cat
remote_addrs = 1.1.1.1
moose
remote_addrs = 3.3.3.3
woodchuck
```